# how to copy data, change one column, and also update related table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This might be an easy task, but feels hard with my limited sql skills.

I have two tables:

```
table1

id  table2_id value
1   2         a
2   2         b
3   1         c

table2

id  value
1   one
2   hello
3   three
4   hello
```

The question is, how do I copy data from table2 where value=='hello' and insert back to table2, and update table1 with the corresponding values?

So in the end, the two tables end up looking like this:

```
table1

id  table2_id value
1   2         a
2   2         b
3   1         c
4   5         a
5   5         b
6   6         a
7   6         b

table2

id  value
1   one
2   hello
3   three
4   hello
5   hello  -- copied from 2
6   hello  -- copied from 4
```

hopefully, this makes sense.

Comment: Where is that third Hello coming from under ID 6 in table 2, using the logic you outline it should only copy accross id 4 and 5?

Comment: Also, where are the values in table 1 coming from?

Comment: @OwainEsau, sorry meant to add 4 to the original table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you want. I'd prefer this one:

```
DECLARE 
    @output TABLE (id int) --here we'll store identities of rows newly copied into Table2  

INSERT Table2 (value) 
    OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @output(id) --presave identities
SELECT value --copy the hello-rows
    FROM Table2
    WHERE value='hello'

INSERT Table1 (table2_id, value)
SELECT id, 'a' FROM @output --you could change the logic of 'a' and 'b' values, it's unclear for me from the conditions
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 'b' FROM @output
```

Comment: Never seem 'inserted.id' before. Thanks!